# Execution failed exception

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I run the app in the android studio, I get this error

> Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   pre-dex
>   'C:\Users\abbasooo.android\build-cache\02f0747de7a8d30b23f383d74adce1e1ad5192a4\output\jars\classes.jar'
>
> to
>
> 'C:\Users\abbasooo\Desktop\tesssst\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\10\classes_571d6b5e229e10768234d4a86b076939bc9a4c44'**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abbasooo.tesssst"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml**strong text**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.abbasooo.tesssst">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What happens when you clean and rebuild the project?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem and i solved it using the following:

Try using "multiDexEnabled true" in the

defaultConfig { } in build.gradle

If it does not solve the problem, then use

android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication", in the  tag of Android Manifest.

If the problem persists, use
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=5120m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

in the gradle.properties file.

Comment: I forgot one thing. you have add compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' in the build.gradle file also.

Answer (score 0):

Three way could work for the problem :

1. Clean and rebuild project or try some basic troubleshoot.
2. Recreate project.
3. Reinstall Android Studio.